# d3 donut pie chart how to refresh data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using pie chart from d3 http://bl.ocks.org/nnattawat/9368297

I am using different set of data:

```
    _data = [{
                "label": "one",
                "value": 20
                },
            {
                "label": "two",
                "value": 50
                },
            {
                "label": "three",
                "value": 30
                }];
```

I have it displayed but i have problem with refreshing it in code fragment

```
if(!svg){
...
} else {
    g.data(pie(d3.entries(_data))).exit().remove();

    g.select("path")
         .transition().duration(200)
         .attrTween("d", arcTween);

    g.select("text")
         .attr("transform", function (d) {
              return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
         });

         svg.select("text.text-tooltip").datum(_data);

         function arcTween(a) {
             var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
             this._current = i(0);
             return function (t) {
                 return arc(i(t));
             };
         }
}
```

With this code i have tooltip and text from labels displayed in different position but arcs are displayed incorrectly

edited from http://bl.ocks.org/nnattawat/9368297 Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sp4hvwh3/

I dont understand why on refresh it is not displayed properly.

This fiddle presents what i am working with http://jsfiddle.net/8fue95u3/4/

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: For starters, you're using `g.select` instead of `g.selectAll`
Also, I can see you exiting old data, but not entering new data. You might want to follow something more like the pattern set out 
[here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/#entering) or [here](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3808218). Or create a fiddle/plunkr/codepen, which we can use to understand your code.

Comment: Can you use my jsfiddle and explain what i am doing wrong?